# How can I download SPSS for macbook?

Tags: macos, spss

I need to SPSS for free for my macbook? I know SPSS is IBM production and its expensive but I want to know is there any way to download SPSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are short-term trial versions, and there are inexpensive academic versions, but you would be violating the license agreement to try and use a cracked version.